# How can I take a few strings and put them in Pastebin, using the Pastebin API?

Tags: python, api, pastebin

I'm working on a project right now, and it involves holding a lot of names, prices, etc. for a few different items. I want to be able to put all these items in a Pastebin paste.

I'm using Python 2.7, if it matters (I think `urllib.urlopen` is for Python 2.x and `urllib.request.urlopen` is for Python 3.x)

Here's my code right now:

```
#-*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-
import urllib

pastebin_vars = {'api_dev_key':'57fe1369d02477a235057557cbeabaa1','api_option':'paste','api_paste_code':'testing pastebin right now'}
response = urllib.urlopen('http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'[, urllib.parse.urlencode(pastebin_vars)[, read().encode('UTF-8')]])
```

Is there something wrong with the format or something? Here's the error I get when running the .py file:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

I've tried playing around with the code. Since I got the `AttributeError`, I took out the part that said `.parse` and got this error:

```
NameError: Name 'read' is not defined
```

After that, I took out the part that said `read().` and got this error:

```
NameError: Name 'encode' is not defined
```

Then I sighed, but removed the part that said `,encode('UTF-8')` and had nothing return after executing the code.

So, what's up? What am I doing wrong? =/

Comment: Errr - it juts looks like you've copied pasted out of the documentation... From what you've you posted, I'm surprised the interpreter isn't having a (more of a) yell at you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `urllib.urlencode()`

```
#-*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-
import urllib

pastebin_vars = {'api_dev_key':'57fe1369d02477a235057557cbeabaa1','api_option':'paste','api_paste_code':'testing pastebin right now'}
response = urllib.urlopen('http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php', urllib.urlencode(pastebin_vars))
url = response.read()

>>> print url
http://pastebin.com/4wfzATQR
```